# Base Class method accessing Derived Class members

Tags: c++

I have following scenario :

```
class num {
    public:
    void print(ostream* o); // Prints the n variable
};

class int_num : public num{
    public:
    int n; // Initialized by this class's constructor
};

class float_num : public num{
    public:
    float n; // Initialized by this class's constructor
};

class double_num : public num{
    public:
    double n; // Initialized by this class's constructor
};
```

How do I implement such a scheme

Answer (score 4):

Give it a virtual method, to be implemented in the derived types:

```
class num {
 public:
    void print(ostream& o) const
    {  // Prints the n variable
      doPrint(o);
    }
 private:
    virtual void doPrint(ostream& os) const = 0;
};

class double_num : public num{
  public:
    double n; // Initialized by this class's constructor
 private:
  void doPrint(ostream& os) const 
  {
    os << n;
  }
};
```

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right, I was thinking of a different problem. I edited that out.

Comment: What is the advantage of having a public print and a private pure virtual doPrint, instead of a single public pure virtual print (or doPrint) ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `template`:

```
template<typename T>
class num
{
    T n;  //data of type T

 public:

      //add constructor(s) to initialize n

      void print(std::ostream &out) { out << n ; }

      //add functions(s) to work with n
};
```

That can do the printing.

Now you have two options:

- Use `typedef` if all the derived types in your code are doing the same thing, nothing type specific:

  ```
  //use typedefs
  typedef num<int>    int_num; 
  typedef num<float>  float_num; 
  typedef num<double> double_num;
  ```
- Or use inheritance **if** you need to do *type* specific things in the derived class:

  ```
  class int_num : public num<int>
  {
     //int specific things 
  };
  ```

The point is that `num<T>` can do the printing irrespective of whether you use `typedef` or *inheritance*.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

One is to make `print()` pure virtual and implement it in derived classes, as others have already pointed out.

The other option is to use the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), like this:

```
template <typename Impl>
class num
{
public:
  void print(ostream &os) const
  {
    os << static_cast<const Impl*>(this)->n;
  }
};

class int_num : public num<int_num>
{
  //same as before
};

class float_num : public num<float_num>
{
  //same as before
};

//etc.
```

Comment: I had never heard of the CRTP idiom before. Interesting! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions. The first is to make the `print` method a pure abstract method and implement it in all child classes. The second is to use templates:

```
template<typename T>
class num
{
public:
    void print(std::ostream& os) const
        {
            os << num_;
        }

private:
    T num_;
};

typedef num<float> float_num;
typedef num<int>     int_num;
```